# $interval is not allowing me to update my front end

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to create a landing page where the picture and accompanying caption updates, showing all of the images and captions in an array of objects (pictures with captions). I think it needs to use $interval or $timeout.

My JS that will show a single picture that does not update:

```
.controller('userCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $timeout) {
    var Picture = Parse.Object.extend("Picture");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Picture);
    query.find({
         success: function(pictures){
             var x = pictures.length;
             var getRandomImage = function () {
                 var imageCount = x
                 var index = Math.floor(
                     ( Math.random() * imageCount * 2 ) % imageCount);
                 return( pictures[ index ] );
                } 
              $scope.image = getRandomImage();

           })
```

My JS that I think should work, creating a randomly scrolling line of pictures:

```
.controller('userCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $timeout) {
    var Picture = Parse.Object.extend("Picture");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Picture);
    query.find({
         success: function(pictures){
             var x = pictures.length;
             var getRandomImage = function () {
                 var imageCount = x
                 var index = Math.floor(
                     ( Math.random() * imageCount * 2 ) % imageCount);
                 return( pictures[ index ] );
             }
             $scope.image = $timeout(function(){getRandomImage();}, 3000);

           })
```

The key portion of my HTML:

```
<img id="logo" src= {{image.get('logo').url()}}>
<p>
   This is a picture ${{image.get('caption')}}
</p>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work as expected, what is the problem exactly? You're not even using $interval in the included code segments.

Comment: I tried it with $timeout and $interval. I've seen examples of both and I could get neither to work at all. To be clear. I want to show one picture and caption on my landing page. Every few seconds 3000ms, in this case a new picture and caption should appear.

Comment: Show us some code you tried, and we'll try helping you fix it.

Comment: I posted the code I tried. The only difference is that where it says $timeout I also tried $interval. Could you be more clear on how I could/should elaborate on this?

Comment: `$timeout` does not return `getRandomImage` result, try move assigning inside timeout func like `$timeout(function(){$scope.image = getRandomImage();}, 3000);`

Comment: @Grundy, right and neither does $interval. How do I get getRandomImage to return a different result every few seconds? Yes, I tried that also along with interval:$timeout(function(){$scope.image = getRandomImage();}, 3000); AND $interval(function(){$scope.image = getRandomImage();}, 3000);

Comment: also i not sure but methinks you do `return` before calling timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move assigning inside interval func, and also you don't need create function `getRandomImage` on every callback, so you can try something like this

```
.controller('userCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $timeout) {
    function getRandomImage(pictures) {
        var imageCount = pictures.length,
            index = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * imageCount * 2 ) % imageCount);
        return( pictures[ index ] );
    }

    var Picture = Parse.Object.extend("Picture");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Picture);
    query.find({
        success: function(pictures){
            $interval(function(){$scope.image = getRandomImage(pictures);}, 3000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$scope.image = $timeout(function(){getRandomImage();}, 3000);
```

is placing the return value of the $timeout call into the $scope.image variable, and that return value (as per the $timeout [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)) is a promise object.

Instead, you probably want to place the return value of the getRandomImage function into your image variable, after a certain timeout, like this:

```
$timeout(function(){$scope.image = getRandomImage();}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. $interval actually worked:                 $interval(function(){$scope.image = getRandomImage();}, 3000);